# Proxmox VE doesn't want to login using WUI interface

Tags: virtual-machine, proxmox

I have access to the proxmox VE server with SSH. But the WUI refuses to login (usingLinux PAM standard authentication realm). It doesn't show any error but just the infinite loading state.

What step should I do to debug and resolve this problem?

I also want to add, in the console, when I tried to do : lxc-ls or lxc-stop to list the VMs or stop a machine, it doesn't respond either

`tail /var/log/daemon.log`

There is nothing special

```
Dec 11 16:13:10 med1 rrdcached[1661]: removing old journal /var/lib/rrdcached/journal/rrd.journal.1512997990.176830
Dec 11 17:13:10 med1 rrdcached[1661]: flushing old values
Dec 11 17:13:10 med1 rrdcached[1661]: rotating journals
Dec 11 17:13:10 med1 rrdcached[1661]: started new journal /var/lib/rrdcached/journal/rrd.journal.1513008790.176831
Dec 11 17:13:10 med1 rrdcached[1661]: removing old journal /var/lib/rrdcached/journal/rrd.journal.1513001590.176805
Dec 11 17:13:16 med1 smartd[1574]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 162 to 157
Dec 11 17:32:37 med1 systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec 11 17:32:37 med1 systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec 11 17:33:55 med1 systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec 11 17:33:55 med1 systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

Also file `~/.xsession-errors` doesn't exist.

Where do you think Proxmox VE store authentification? Maybe a restart/reload help?

Comment: `tail /var/log/daemon.log`

Comment: In general, in "x can't login" problems also `~/.xsession-errors` is a good place.

Comment: @peterh, proxmox VE is a web-based virtualisation solution.

Comment: Are you logging in against the PAM domain or proxmox own authentication? When you say Proxmox, you mean Promox VE right? When you say GUI, you mean WUI right?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't know if GUI or WUI but it's the web interface. Realm Linux PAM standard authentification.

Comment: please post the output of `tail /var/log/daemon.log` : )

Comment: @lese Edited. Nothing seems valuable :(